# BLDC motor with a common enabled configuration

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motordriver

Can a BLDC motor be driven with a common enable configuration? To be more precise, without the possibility to leave a phase of the motor floating. Every phase must either be connected to Vcc or to GND.

I am aware this a less than comfortable configuration but I am trying to reuse an old gimbal for a project (the main board with 3 3-phase drivers and a controller, and 3 bldc motors). Since the board is connected this way it should be possible, but i have no idea how.